# How to find remain factor of this trigonometic equation?

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving, factoring

The equation $$3\sin^2 x - 3\cos x -6\sin x + 2\sin 2x + 3=0$$ has a solution $x = 0$. That is mean it has a factor $\cos x - 1$. I tried write the given equation has the form
$$(\cos x - 1)P(x)=0.$$ I am looking for the factor $P(x)$. How to do that?

Comment: You'd need to express all the trigonometric functions in terms of $\sin x$ and its powers first.

Comment: Do you mean it has a solution $\sin x = 1$? If $x = 0$ is a solution, you cannot divide out a factor $(\sin x - 1)$.

Comment: I am sorry. I repaired my question. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have to write it in terms of (cosx - 1)?  I see a sine quadratic there too.  I'm not sure what you are asking...do you specifically need to have cosx-1 as a factor?

Comment: I would rather translate the expression with $tan(x/2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\implies 3\left(\sin^2x-2\sin x+1\right)+2\sin2x-3\cos x=0$$

$$\implies 3\left(1-\sin x\right)^2+\cos x(4\sin x-3)=0$$

$$\text{We know,}\sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},\cos2x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\text{ where }t=\tan\frac x2$$

So, $1-\sin x=\frac{(1-t)^2}{1+t^2}, 4\sin x-3=4\frac{2t}{1+t^2}-3=-\frac{3t^2-8t+3}{1+t^2}$

$$\implies 3\left(\frac{(1-t)^2}{1+t^2}\right)^2-\frac{(1-t^2)}{1+t^2}\frac{(3t^2-8t+3)}{1+t^2}=0$$

If $t$ is finite, $$3(1-t)^4-(1-t)(1+t)(3t^2-8t+3)=0$$

$$\text{Or, }(1-t)\{3(1-t)^3-(1+t)(3t^2-8t+3)\}=0$$

If $t=1, \tan\frac x2=1\implies \frac x2=n\pi+\frac\pi4\implies x=2n\pi+\frac\pi2$ where $n$ is any integer .

Else  $$2t(3t^2-7t+2)=0$$

If $t=0,t=2m\pi+0$  where $m$ is any integer  (like the previous case)

Else $3t^2-7t+2=0$ (Solve the Quadratic Equation and find $x$ like the previous cases )

Finally, if $t$ is  $+\infty,\frac x2=r\pi+\frac\pi2, x=2r\pi+\pi=(2r+1)\pi$ where $r$ is any integer

if $t$ is  $-\infty,\frac x2=s\pi-\frac\pi2, x=2s\pi-\pi=(2s-1)\pi$ where $s$ is any integer

In the last two case $x$ is an odd multiple of $\pi$ which does **not** satisfy the given equation

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the simplest way to factor out the zero-ing function is to use a half angle.  For example, I rewrite your equation as

$$\sin{\frac{x}{2}} \left [ 2 \cos{\frac{x}{2}} ( 3 \sin{x} + 4 \cos{x} - 6) + 6 \sin{\frac{x}{2}} \right ] = 0$$

Note that

$$\sin{\frac{x}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos{x}}{2}}$$

so the $1-\cos{x}$ factor you wanted is there, in a way.

Answer (score 0):

LHS$=sinx(3sinx-2)+4sinx(cox-1)-3(cosx-1)=\sqrt{1-cos^2 x}(3sinx-2)+4sinx(cox-1)-3(cosx-1)=\sqrt{|cosx-1||cosx+1|}(3sinx-2)+4sinx(cox-1)-3(cosx-1)$

if you insist $cosx-1$ as a factor, it has $\sqrt{|cosx-1|}$,but not $cosx-1$.

if you simply want to solve it, $1-cosx=2sin^2 \dfrac{x}{2}$,$sinx=2sin\dfrac{2}{2}cos\dfrac{x}{2}$, so more straight forward. $sin\dfrac{x}{2}$ may be a better choice.